# Play! - End Job dynamically

Tags: java, singleton, playframework

So, let's say I start a job from a controller asynchronously and then render some template.

```
MyJob job = new MyJob();
job.doJob();

render();
```

MyJob looks like:

import play.jobs.*;

```
public class MyJob extends Job {

    public void doJob() {
        // execute some application logic here until I say to quit via a controller method
    }

}
```

From the UI, I do some actions, and I trigger a request to another route in the controller which would end the job.  I don't want to have complicated, continuous DAO actions handled on the client side, so what is the best way to go about this? I have an EC2 elastic cache setup, so the main problem is assigning an ID to a job.

```
 job.endJob(id); ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at  [JobsPlugin](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/jobs/JobsPlugin.java) class - it uses `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor` to maintain a list of jobs.

This class has a [remove](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#remove%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method, which you can try to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to easily stop a Job. As Play is stateless, probably your best bet would be to have some flag in the database that the job can check to decide to stop, but doesn't look a great solution to me.

Have you checked [Continuations](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/asynchronous#SuspendingHTTPrequests) in Play? I believe they may suit your scenario better.

Comment: I did see those, but I need the request to return other things. I decided to just use singleton to check for a flag. It's not pretty, but it was less beautiful in javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static ScheduledFuture<?> future;
private static final TestJob testJob = new TestJob();

future = JobsPlugin.executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(testJob, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

future.cancel(true);

future = JobsPlugin.executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(testJob, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```